# How can I trigger multiple clicks on the same element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Javascript code I have this strings:

```
$('.promo_menu:nth-child(1)').click();
$('.avatar_0').click();
```

The problem is that the data lines should emulate 2 clicks on certain Beams. But no clicks.

I tried to write something like this:

```
$('.promo_menu:nth-child(1)').trigger('click');
$('.avatar_0').trigger('click');
```

But the result has not changed, clicks do not work.

But after the page is fully loaded and I'll write the code in the console:

```
$('.promo_menu:nth-child(1)').trigger('click');
$('.avatar_0').trigger('click');
```

Everything clicked.
I tried this code to run through the $(document).ready(){};

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.promo_menu:nth-child(1)').click();
        $('.avatar_0').click();
});
```

No results...
How can solve this situation? I need 2 clicks at the end of loading my page.

Comment: What should happen when the click event is triggered?

Comment: Do you update any html element with js or jquery after the page is loaded?

Comment: Vohuman, many things... Work function.

Comment: plbsam, after click I updated many things on the page, but now it's not working, onyl if I write this events in Dev Tools Console.

Comment: Are these elements created in your javascript code?

Comment: Yes, these elements writed in the same file.

Comment: What's a "Beam"? Show some HTML, please.

Comment: did you try "triger('click')" inside "document.ready(..);"?

Comment: You did not bind the click events to the items. You need to do [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/k64s8d7r/). You can even place the element's event in the HTML and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have these functions running as soon as the page is loaded, `$(document).ready()` will not be enough. After the document is ready you must bind the events after the elements have loaded. So to be sure the elements have loaded use `$(window).load()`

example:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).load(function()
    {
        $('.promo_menu:nth-child(1)').click();
        $('.avatar_0').click();
    });
});
```

Comment: But there's no need to wrap a `$(window).load()` into a `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is enough, it loads the entire DOM. It's not like we are waiting for an image to load or something.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I am understanding correctly, these 2 clicks should **only** happen on page load, right? If so, you could try just call the event handler function directly instead?

```
$(function () {
   $('.promo_menu').on('click', promoMenuClickHandler);
   $('.avatar_0').on('click', avatarClickHandler);

   // call handler, preserving 'this' context
   promoMenuClickHandler.call($('.promo_menu:nth-child(1)')[0]);
   avatarClickHandler.call($('.avatar_0')[0]);


   function promoMenuClickHandler() {
     // ...
   }

   function avatarClickHandler() {
     // ...
   }
});
```

(**Note**: the code above is only an example from the roughly two lines of code provided in the qeustion.)

That being said, there is no reason why your `.trigger` attempt should not work either. Are you sure the code is being executed? Are you sure you trigger these clicks *after* you bind your click handlers?